# NOT A GROUP BY EXPRESSION ERROR (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Below is my sql query in oracle 12c. I'm using sqlplus. It's prompting the error "ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression". I don't know what when wrong here. Please help.

```
PROMPT Type the speciality
ACCEPT speciality PROMPT "Speciality: "
SELECT assignment.doctor_id, doctors.name, MAX(assignment.end_assignment) AS end_contract,
(SELECT doctor_availability.end_availability
 FROM doctor_availability
 JOIN doctor_specialities ON doctor_specialities.doctor_id = doctors.id
 AND UPPER(doctor_specialities.specialities) like UPPER('%&speciality%'))
FROM assignment
JOIN doctors ON doctors.id = assignment.doctor_id
JOIN doctor_availability ON doctor_availability.doctor_id = assignment.doctor_id
WHERE doctor_availability.end_availability > 'end_contract'
GROUP BY assignment.doctor_id;
```

[image]

Comment: You need to `GROUP BY` `doctors.name` as well as `assignment.doctor_id`

Comment: Could it be that here: SELECT doctor_availability.end_availability
 FROM doctor_availability
 JOIN doctor_specialities ON doctor_specialities.doctor_id = doctors.id you have to use doctor_availability.doctors.id becaus you join the table doctor_availability with the table doctor_specialities

Answer (score 3):

Normally if you use the Group by clause you have to put there all the fields which you select without a aggregat function. In your case you select assignment.doctor_id, doctors.name without a aggregate function but in the group by clause you have only the assignment.doctor_id.
Try this

```
SELECT assignment.doctor_id, doctors.name, MAX(assignment.end_assignment) AS end_contract,
(SELECT doctor_availability.end_availability
 FROM doctor_availability
 JOIN doctor_specialities ON doctor_specialities.doctor_id = doctors.id
 AND UPPER(doctor_specialities.specialities) like UPPER('%&speciality%'))
FROM assignment
JOIN doctors ON doctors.id = assignment.doctor_id
JOIN doctor_availability ON doctor_availability.doctor_id = assignment.doctor_id
WHERE doctor_availability.end_availability > 'end_contract'
GROUP BY assignment.doctor_id, doctors.name
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to contain all your select values in the group by.

```
PROMPT Type the speciality
ACCEPT speciality PROMPT "Speciality: "
SELECT assignment.doctor_id, doctors.name, MAX(assignment.end_assignment) AS end_contract,
(SELECT doctor_availability.end_availability
FROM doctor_availability
JOIN doctor_specialities ON doctor_specialities.doctor_id = doctors.id
AND UPPER(doctor_specialities.specialities) like UPPER('%&speciality%'))
FROM assignment
JOIN doctors ON doctors.id = assignment.doctor_id
JOIN doctor_availability ON doctor_availability.doctor_id = assignment.doctor_id
WHERE doctor_availability.end_availability > 'end_contract'
GROUP BY assignment.doctor_id, doctors.name, doctor_availability.end_availability;
```

Comment: I had tried by adding the doctors.name earlier but it still the same error. I updated the with the error screenshot.

Comment: Thats because there is a subselect in the select statement as well, and this is not in the group by statement.

Comment: @Matt, it is still the same error.

Comment: @t3es screenshot the error again please with the additional group by in there